# Connecting to MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to connect to my cluster on MongoDB Atlas using MongoDB compass using the string provided by Atlas `mongodb+srv://<user-id>:<password>@<url>`. Not able to connect. Connection just get closed.

Also tried from command line the mongostat command with the similar string provided by Atlas. There I am getting the error given below.

> 2021-05-25T10:30:44.987+0530    could not connect to server: server
> selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type:
> Single, Servers: [{ Addr: :27017, Type: Unknown, State:
> Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() :
> connection(:27017[-45]) incomplete read of message header: EOF },
> ] }.

Please help.

Comment: If possible, put the error in Blockquote for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

You have to to make sure the **mongod** daemon, is running the background process, before trying to connect to **MongoDB ATlas** using **MongoDB Compass**, else data requests, data access and background management process would not work.
[about mongod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/)
To get **MongoDB Compass**, connected to your **MongoDB Atlas**

1. You could **cd** change directory to the installation path of **MongoDB**, and manually run **mongod.exe** command before connecting as seen below:
   [image: change directory to mongodb installation path]
2. And then run, the **mongod.exe** to start the daemon process as seen below
   [image: mongod daemon process running]

**NOTE** Or you could set your **mongod** process in your **system environment variables**, so it automatically starts when, your pc boots up: as seen as this also:
[image: set mongod in environment variables]

3. Then you can connect to your **MongoDB Atlas Cluster** using the connection string provided as seen below:
   [image: Connecting to mongodb atlas using connection string]
4. Below is the list of databases and collection in my atlas cluster:
   [image: Databases in my Shared Atlas Cluster]

Comment: Issue got resolved by adding the IP in Atlas from which I was trying access Atlas. Thank you.